# Best way to create a reuseable blog component for multiple sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a site, where I want to include a blog-like feature. I know there are a lot of standard solutions out there, but as I'm semi-new to Ruby on Rails, then I want to create it myself to learn more stuff. (And you all know that there are a million ways to make a Post table.)

The thing is that I want this component I'm creating to be reusable to be able to power my personal blog in the future. So how would all your Ruby on Rails experts recommend to make a component that has some models, migrations and maybe some standard views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rails engines](http://www.stubbleblog.com/index.php/2011/04/writing-rails-engines-getting-started/). These are small Ruby on Rails applications that you can embed in your main application. They can contain all major elements of an application, including routes, migrations, models, controllers, etc. So a widget application could drop in your blog engine to whip up widget blogs in no time.

Comment: Thank you for the link. :) Looks like there is some good tips in there as well.

Comment: The link seems to be broken (times out).

Answer (score 1):

A Rails Engine.

- http://www.stubbleblog.com/index.php/2011/04/writing-rails-engines-getting-started/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/

Comment: The first link seems to be broken (times out).